# How can I add or remove any files into and from initramfs root file system?

Tags: file, system, root, uclinux

As I entitled, I want to manipulate the root file system of my uClinux.
It is based on initramfs.

I know /usr has most of the files which related to make root file system.

```
├── .built-in.o.cmd
├── .gen_init_cpio.cmd
├── .gitignore
├── .initramfs_data.cpio.gz.cmd
├── .initramfs_data.cpio.gz.d
├── .initramfs_data.o.cmd
├── Kconfig
├── Makefile
├── built-in.o
├── gen_init_cpio
├── gen_init_cpio.c
├── initramfs_data.S
└── initramfs_data.cpio.gz
```

This is it.

And there is a directory, ../romfs, which seems to be used as the root file system.
There is a directory ../romfs/mnt/
And I want to make a directory ../romfs/mnt/flash
But mkdir ../romfs/mnt/flash doesn't help.
Downloaded image doesn't include ../romfs/mnt/flash
And actually ../romfs/mnt/flash is removed right after the compilation.

How can I add or remove any directory to my root file system?

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me post my solution to this problem of mine.
I am posting this as an answer because it has volume too big to be put to comments to other's answer or my question.

First I searched for **fstab** under the top directory of my project.

```
find -name "fstab"
```

The result is shown below.

```
./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/fstab
./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/fstab
./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/fstab
./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/fstab
./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/fstab
./romfs/etc/fstab
```

**./romfs/etc/fstab** is copied from one of the **fstab** s under **./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/** s.

BINGO! **./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/** includes everything I need.

looking up **./vendors/{vendorname}/{modelname}/Makefile** explains everything.

I hope someone who found this question and answers can get useful information here!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How is your kernel/initramfs build ? Is it Buildroot or ptxdist or similar tool ?

You need to know what is done during the compilation/build phase, maybe there is a skeleton elsewhere and you need to add your flash dir into this skeleton.

Comment: Thanks! Right! Let me post my solutions to this problem of myself.